# Editable grid cell text is not displayed completely?

Tags: gwt, extjs, gxt

I have an editable grid. in one of the cell i have entered more than 4000 chars. But the problem is only 4000 characters are visible and remaining are invisible but they are there in the cell.if i select invisible area with mouse then they are visible. The scenario is whenever the cell has more than 4000 chars it will happen and only 4000 are displayed and rest of them are invisible.PFB screen shots.

text invisible in the screen shot but it has text.
[image]

text is visible if i select with mouse:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. is it possible to make it black? Thanks

Comment: use color:#000; in your input css to change the color to black

Comment: Actually there are in white..once u select using mouse they will be in white color..

Comment: also your input width is not filling the containing box

Comment: Do i need give width to text box?

Comment: Well without a width i believe they use a default width

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a renderer to that cell:

```
GridCellRenderer<BaseModel> renBIG = new GridCellRenderer<BaseModel>() {
   @Override
    public Object render(BaseModel model, String property, com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex, ListStore<BaseModel> store, Grid<BaseModel> grid) {
                    return "<div style='width:100%; white-space: normal;'>" + (String) model.get("CELLNAME") + "</div>";
                }
            };
    columnBIG.setRenderer(renBIG );
```